# convert infopath form to html form

Tags: batch-file, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I need to convert infopath form to html form (Logic & visual)
Someone knows how i can do it automatically with batch script
 or other language script like php ?

hope you can help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoPath File *.xsn is just a Zip file.  You can change the extension to MyForm.zip and extract all the internal files.  Most of the files will be xml for the data and xsl for the Views.  You can use whatever scripting language you want that convert them to  something else.  The xsl is mostly HMTL with  xsl added where the data is supposed to go.

Comment: This didn't work for me, windows didn't recognize the zip (zero contents), however, I just used 7zip to directly extract the *.xsn file.

Comment: *.xsn is a cabinet file (*.cab).  Changing the file extension should allow you to extract the contents.